# How to calculate distance between geographic points and boundaries?

Tags: r, mapping, geospatial, spatial, qgis

I have around 50,000 geocoded properties and need to find the distance between the properties, formatted as spatial points, to the nearest school zone boundary which is formatted as a spatial polyogon. I'm able to associate and map the points and polygons together, and I've joined the school zone attributes to the properties that are located in the specific school zone with QGIS, but I need the distance. Ideally I'd like to do this in QGIS or R, but I'm open to anything else that could do it.

Comment: Check out `spatstat::nncross`. You're essentially looking for a KNN algorithm. I think you have to convert SP to the `spatstat` spatial data type.

Comment: Yes, @Mako212 is right, to do this in `spatstat` you would have to convert the spatial points to a `ppp` and reduce the polygon to a `psp` containing the edges of the polygon and then call `nncross`, but it may be more natural to use `sf::st_distance` or `rgeos::gDistance`.

Answer (score 3):

Consider `gDistance()` from `rgeos` package. It works for point to polygon distances.

Edit (on 2018-10-22):

This answer was built on understanding of workflow of the `sp` package, in workflow built on the highly recommended `sf` package please consider `sf::st_distance()` instead.